# Calculating the Jacobian using the Eigen library

Tags: eigen

I want to be able to compute the Jacobian matrix using the `Eigen` C++ library, but I cannot find any documentation on how to do this.

Previously, I have achieved this using the `numdifftools` package in Python. The function is:

```
numdifftools.Jacobian(ForwardsFunction)([input 1, input 2, input 3, ....])
```

Here, `ForwardsFunction` is a user-defined function which calculates the output state given the input state (`[input 1, input 2, input 3, ...]`). The `numdifftools.Jacobian()` method then automatically calculates the Jacobian for these input values, presumable using some automatic differentiation.

Is there an equivalent function in the `Eigen` library?

Answer (score 1):

There are some tools in Eigen library that perform numerical differentiation.
Take a look at:

https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/group__NumericalDiff__Module.html
https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/classEigen_1_1AutoDiffScalar.html

You might notice, that those modules are "unsupported" (not a part of a official Eigen library). The reasoning is the following: Eigen is a library for linear algebra, thus manipulating with sparse and dense matrices, and numerical differentiation are a little bit on the edge of its scope. - So the priority of including them inside the library is lower. Those modules, as far as I know, are used in their solvers in a very specific way. I don't have an experience of using those Eigen::Numerical Differentiation classes in my project, though you might give it a try.

https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/classEigen_1_1NumericalDiff.html